# How do I delete my community account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

How do I delete my Game Development Stack Exchange account, specifically?

Comment: Let's everybody remember our "be nice" policy okay? It's not appropriate to be sniping at the original poster for any reason; that won't change any perceived or real issues and will only encourage the perception that this is a "toxic" community.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to involve the community team to delete your Game Development account. Instructions for doing so can be found [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account). Be sure to specify that it's only your Game Development account you are interested in removing. The community team will work with you from there.

I'd be curious to know more about your reasons, though. From my perspective this desire seems rather abrupt.

Answer (score -2):

I am assuming you mean you wish to *delete* your account. The only thing close to "unsubscribe" would be 'unsubscribing from emails', but your mini-rant suggests this is *not* what you want.

We have an excellent resource for questions like this, already. It's called [the Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help), and it has a page dedicated to ["how do I delete my account"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).

Given that you have made posts on the regular<sup>1</sup> site, you can not simply delete the account, yourself.

> If you *have* voted or posted, please contact the Stack Exchange Team:
>
> Visit the [contact form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and select 'I need to delete my user profile.' After you contact us, the team will reach out with further instructions.
>
> <sub>- [That page your asked to read when you first sign up, and again when your question is closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help)</sub>

---

Please take this with a grain of salt: In the real world, people are going to disagree with you. If you throw in the towel over one or two people disagreeing with you, especially when there is evidence of many more users trying to *help* you, your going to have a bad time.

In *game developing*, your going to receive criticism, too. It is important to be mature about this sort of thing. Criticism can reveal key issues in your game, but your reaction to criticism may reveal key issues to *others*.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Regular referring to the non-meta site</sub>

Comment: Yes, I want to unsubscribe to this particular community. Instead of a whole story couldn't you instead, have answered my question? I can be perfectly civil, and I, in fact, always am. The thing is, this community disgusts me, with the pretense that they know what they're talking about, while downvoting me at the same time. So, could you tell me this one thing: how do I leave gamvedev.stackexchange.com. That was my question, please if you don't know the answer, could you refrain from posting an *answer*?

Comment: So, let me state this one more time, as clearly as I possibly can: I want to unsubscribe to gamedev.stackexchange. Not the whole stackexchange community. They are pretty awesome. except here. I want to unsubscribe from HERE. Can you answer that?

Comment: Yeah, if just that comment was your answer, I bet you wouldn't have got the downvotes you did, don't you think? I asked one simple thing, you wrote a wall of text as an "answer". Note that I cannot downvote, my reputation isn't enough for that, so other people saw how toxic you were being and decided to show you that. There may be a hope for this community afterall. Anyway, I'm not sticking around to see it, so peace out.

Comment: @FinnTheHuman, as a mature adult, I accept the downvotes as a difference of opinion. I agree that the second part, in retrospect, is no longer very useful (it is localised to you, after all), but it is important to point out how easy it is to get this information, ones self.